# Aggregate function returns the blank array value using Mognodb and Node.js

Tags: node.js, mongodb, aggregate

I am using `MongoDB aggregate` method to fetch the data from collection but it returns me the blank value.

> collection::restaurant-

```
{cosine:"America",name:"brooklyn","grades":[{status:"A","amount":500},{status:"B","amount":300},{status:"C","amount":150}]},
{cosine:"Indian",name:"Arya","grades":[{status:"A","amount":1000},{status:"B","amount":700},{status:"C","amount":400}]},
{cosine:"Thai",name:"Crooks","grades":[{status:"A","amount":5000},{status:"B","amount":3000},{status:"C","amount":200}]},
{cosine:"Chinise",name:"China sea","grades":[{status:"A","amount":1500},{status:"B","amount":890},{status:"C","amount":500}]}
```

The above is my collection data. I am using the following code to fetch the matched record.

```
db.restaurant.aggregate([
            {$match:{grades:{status:"A"}}}
    ]).toArray((err, docs)=>{
        if (err) {
            console.log('err',err);
            res.send(err);
        }else{
            console.log('docs',docs);
            res.send(docs);
        }
    })
```

Here in console I am getting the blank array. I need to fetch the record whose `grades status=A`.

Comment: any error in console? you are facing?

Comment: @Pardeep: No, I am getting this `docs []` message for console.

Comment: will you export your collection?

Comment: try db.restaurant.find({
  grades: {
    $elemMatch: {
      status: "A"
    }
  }
})

Comment: @sushantmehta: I need to use the aggregate method also.

Comment: try db.restaurant.aggregate([
  {
    $match: {
      grades: {
        $elemMatch: {
          status: "A"
        }
      }
    }
  }
])

Comment: @sushantmehta: Yes, it worked as expected but it any other key name has also status field rather than `grades` then I think it wont work.

Comment: above query will only match status in grades array

Comment: upvote comment if it was any useful.

Answer (score 0):

You can try this by $unwind, $unwind pulls the object/array out side so we can match any condition in nested objects.

```
db.restaurant.aggregate([
  { '$unwind': '$grades' },
  { $match: { grades: { status: "A" } } }
]).toArray((err, docs) => {
  if (err) {
    console.log('err', err);
    res.send(err);
  } else {
    console.log('docs', docs);
    res.send(docs);
  }
})
```

Answer (score 0):

This is you Query

```
db.getCollection("stackans").aggregate([
    {
   $unwind : "$grades"   
    },  {
        $match: {
            "grades.status": "A"
        }
    }
]);
```

OutPut

```
/* 1 */
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("5d7275504a3464edefcab2f5"),
    "cosine" : "America",
    "name" : "brooklyn",
    "grades" : {
        "status" : "A",
        "amount" : 500
    }
}

/* 2 */
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("5d72756d4a3464edefcab2fb"),
    "cosine" : "Indian",
    "name" : "Arya",
    "grades" : {
        "status" : "A",
        "amount" : 1000
    }
}

/* 3 */
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("5d7275824a3464edefcab2ff"),
    "cosine" : "Thai",
    "name" : "Crooks",
    "grades" : {
        "status" : "A",
        "amount" : 5000
    }
}

/* 4 */
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("5d7275924a3464edefcab301"),
    "cosine" : "Chinise",
    "name" : "China sea",
    "grades" : {
        "status" : "A",
        "amount" : 1500
    }
```

}